# shiny sorting numbers as strings

Tags: r, sorting, shiny

I'm using shiny and the renderDataTable function from the DT package to show a table in my webapp. When sorting, it seems to be treating the numbers as strings, ordering by first digit then second and so on i.e what should sort to 1, 2, 5, 100, 250 would be sorted to 1, 100, 2, 250, 5

I've tried specifying colClasses when reading the csv, but doesn't seem to work.

server.R shown, my ui.R is just a dataTableOutput

```
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
date <- format(Sys.Date() - 1, '%Y_%m_%d')
date2 <- format(Sys.Date() - 2, '%Y_%m_%d')

# Read data in
tab1 <- read.csv(paste0(date, '_tabs.csv'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE, colClasses = c('character', rep('integer', 9)))
tab1 <- na.omit(tab1)
tab2 <- read.csv(paste0(date2, '_tabs.csv'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE, colClasses = c('character', rep('numeric', 9)))

# Ensuring both tables have matching values for country
tab3 <- tab2[tab2$X %in% tab1$X, ]
missingr <- setdiff(tab1$X, tab3$X)
for (j in missingr) {
  tab3 <- rbind(tab3, rep(0, length(tab1)))
  tab3[nrow(tab3), 1] <- j
}

# Sorting by country and creating a new dataframe of differences
Country <- tab1$X
tab1 <- arrange(tab1, X)
tab3 <- arrange(tab3, X)
tab1 <- tab1[, !(names(tab1) %in% 'X')]
tab3 <- tab3[, !(names(tab3) %in% 'X')]
tab2 <- tab1 - tab3

# Adding total column and country column to dataframes
c1 <- c('Total', colSums(tab1))
c2 <- c('Total', colSums(tab2))
rownames(tab2) <- Country
tab2 <- data.frame(Country, tab2)
tab1 <- data.frame(Country, tab1)
tab1 <- tab1[tab1$total > 100, ]
tab2 <- tab2[tab2$Country %in% tab1$Country, ]
tab1 <- rbind(tab1, c1)
tab2 <- rbind(tab2, c2)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$tab1 <- renderDataTable({tab1},
    rownames = FALSE, options = list(lengthMenu = list(c(20, 10, -1), c('20', '10', 'All')), 
    initComplete = JS("function(settings, json) {","$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});","}"),
      autoWidth = TRUE,
      columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = "_all"))
    ))
  output$tab2 <- renderDataTable({tab2},
    rownames = FALSE, options = list(lengthMenu = list(c(20, 10, -1), c('20', '10', 'All')), 
    initComplete = JS("function(settings, json) {","$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});","}"),
      autowidth = TRUE,
      columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = "_all"))
    ))
}
)
```

Comment: Where are you ordering the table? The `renderDataTable` does not order the table  by default. The section 4.1 of https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html explains the `order-option`.

Comment: Clicking on a column sorts it, as on the page you just linked, the default option of sorting by the leftmost column is what I want initially (sort by country) and then users can click on a column to sort them.

Comment: Try using `str` on the tables you've created. It will tell you what sort of data you have And adding the output to your question would be helpfull.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to post images, but here's the link until someone takes it down http://i.imgur.com/No7SiJT.png pic shows what happens when you click on the leftmost number column to sort. the X column when reading in the csv files is the country code, so that needs to be character anyway. The rest of the columns should be nums/ints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating c1, I didn't realise it was a character vector, when rbinding it to the data frames at the end, the whole data frame ended up being to characters.

Thanks to @user5029763

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem which caused a problem when sorting columns on our Rshiny app as well. We discovered that it was caused by cbind converting our numerical values to strings.

```
> foo=c(111,10,3,4,5)
> bar=c("should","it","order","like","yoda")

> df1 = data.frame(cbind(foo,bar))
> df1[order(df1[,1]),]

  foo    bar
2  10     it
1 111 should
3   3  order
4   4   like
5   5   yoda
```

You can verify this by checking

```
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ foo: Factor w/ 5 levels "10","111","3",..: 2 1 3 4 5
 $ bar: Factor w/ 5 levels "it","like","order",..: 4 1 3 2 5
```

This is because cbind is called first, and then creates an array of chars. When you think about it is natural because an array needs to have all elements of the same type, and numbers can be converted to chars but not the other way around.
This is easily avoided by using cbind on data frame objects instead:

```
> df2 = cbind(data.frame(foo),data.frame(bar))
> df2[order(df2[,1]),]

  foo    bar
3   3  order
4   4   like
5   5   yoda
2  10     it
1 111 should
```

Or in this example case perhaps more elegantly by creating a new data frame from the array of strings and numbers directly:

```
> df3 = data.frame(foo,bar)
> df3[order(df3[,1]),]

  foo    bar
3   3  order
4   4   like
5   5   yoda
2  10     it
1 111 should
```

Answer (score -1):

Under `# Sorting by country and creating a new dataframe of differences` I would include an `as.numeric(tab1$X)`. Generally, you can coerce numeric type values to actual numerics by using that function.

Comment: Going straight from factor to numeric is a great way to lose information, e.g. `year <- factor(1999:2004); as.numeric(year)`. You should always use `as.numeric(as.character(...))`.

Comment: That's true. OP said that they appeared to be 'strings', and the fact that they sort by digits indicates that they are character vectors and not factors.  But you are right.  For safey's sake, it's smart to use as.numeric(as.character(...))

Comment: Factors sort as strings by default, so sorting by digits indicates factor as much as it indicates character. Given the `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` default in R - and that this is a data frame - makes factors **much** more likely. You have to know pretty well what you're doing to get a character vector in a data frame instead of a factor.

Comment: I don't mean to be disagreeable - I just think this is a very risky recommendation as-is. If you edit your question to suggest `as.numeric(as.character(tab1$X))`, or at least suggest looking at `str(tab1)` or `sapply(tab1, class)` to be sure about classes first, I'll happily change my downvote to an upvote.